# Got this error when trying to scrape a website: Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent') what could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

here is the code :

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const getQuotes = async () => {
  // Start a Puppeteer session with:
  // - a visible browser (`headless: false` - easier to debug because you'll see the browser in action)
  // - no default viewport (`defaultViewport: null` - website page will in full width and height)
 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });

  // Open a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
});

  // On this new page:
  // - open the "http://quotes.toscrape.com/" website
  // - wait until the dom content is loaded (HTML is ready)
  await page.goto("https://www.axs.com/browse/music", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
    
    const quotes = await page.evaluate(()=>{
        //fetch the first element with class 'quote'
        const quoteList = document.querySelectorAll('#page-relative-block > div > div.layout-column--primary-lg > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2)');
        return Array.from(quoteList).map((quote)=>{

            //fetch the sub-elements of each element with the class quotes
        const text = quote.querySelector('.headliner').textContent;
        const author = quote.querySelector('.supporting').textContent;
       

        return {text, author}

        });
        
    });

    console.log(quotes)

    await browser.close();

};

// Start the scraping
getQuotes();
```

I tried removing textContent but that didn't fix any thing since it ended up returning undefined
I also tried to user the user agent in the above code but even that doesn't fix anything

Comment: What probably is happing is you are trying to get a text from the unexistent element you have to ensure that the component exists.

Comment: Your comment says _"fetch the first element with class 'quote'"_ but then you're using `querySelectorAll`. Are you meant to grabbing _one_ element as your comment suggests or a node-list like your code suggests. An easy way to fetch the first element with class 'quote' is `querySelector('.quote')`.

Comment: not all the quotes have both of those elements. Probably some quotes missing `supporting` (aka author) information. Or, your query is picking up divs that are not quotes.

Answer (score 0):

as I analyzed the mention issue so I found that "textContent" is not null. Error is saying can't read properties of null. This means **quote.querySelector('.headliner')** is null. You can console.log this and can check why this is null. You are accessing the element that is not exist in DOM. I don't html code so I can't check. I hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably picking up things in DOM that are not quotes, or some of the quotes are missing author or quote for whatever reason. A usable scraper needs to handle the unexpected.

just check for existence of the elements you need...

```
        return Array.from(quoteList).map((quote)=>{

            //fetch the sub-elements of each element with the class quotes
            const quoteElem = quote.querySelector('.headliner');
            const authorElem = quote.querySelector('.supporting');
            if (!quoteElem || !authorElem) return null;
            const text = quoteElem.textContent;
            const author = authorElem.textContent;

            return {text, author}
        })
        .filter((o) => o);
```